# Convertir Excel a JSON y mostrar en tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola tengo un código donde trato de convertir Excel a JSON y después mostrar los registros en HTML como una tabla pero me marca el siguiente error:

ReferenceError: readXlsxFile is not defined at HTMLInputElement.

Segun el console, el error radica en esta linea:
readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data){

Aquí les dejo el código para que me puedan indicar donde esta el error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://unkpg.com/read-excel-file@4.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>-->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "file" id = "input">
    <table id = "tbl-data"></table>

    <script>
        var input=document.getElementById('input');
        input.addEventListener('change', function(){
            readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data){
            var i=0;
            data.map((row, index)=>{
                 if (i==0){
                    let table=document.getElementById('tbl-data');
                    generateTableHead(table, row);
                 }
                 if(i>0){
                    let table=document.getElementById('tbl-data');
                    generateTableRows(table, row);
                 }
                 i++;
            });
        });
    });
    function generateTableHead(table, data){
        let thead=table.createTHead();
        let row=thead.insertRow();
        for(let key of data){
            let th=document.createElement('th');
            let text=document.createTextNode(key);
            th.appendChild(text);
            row.appendChild(th);
        }
    }
    function generateTableRows(table, data){
        let newRow=table.insertRow(-1);
        data.map((row, index)=>{
            let newCell=newRow.insertCell();
            let newText=document.createTextNode(row);
            newCell.appendChild(newText);
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estimado, tiene razón el inconveniente era por el unpkg, ahora ya me pinta la pantalla, excelente! ahora me falta trasladarlo a una tabla con scroll y que el encabezado sea fijo porque mi archivo excel es de 10 columnas con 10 mil registros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el link a **UNPKG** es erróneo, pero al solucionar esto obtenía otro error mas pero esta vez no en mi codigo sino dentro del código proporcionado por el recurso, porque la version es obsoleta quizás pero no me aceptaba mi archivo *.xlsx*. En cualquier caso utiliza este link en tu `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
```

El link lo obtuve de la documentación de [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file#cdn).

Usa este snippet para probar como funciona:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "file" id = "input">
    <table id = "tbl-data"></table>
    <script>
      var input = document.getElementById("input");
      input.addEventListener("change", function () {
        readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function (data) {
          var i = 0;
          data.map((row, index) => {
            if (i == 0) {
              let table = document.getElementById("tbl-data");
              generateTableHead(table, row);
            }
            if (i > 0) {
              let table = document.getElementById("tbl-data");
              generateTableRows(table, row);
            }
            i++;
          });
        });
      });

      function generateTableHead(table, data) {
        let thead = table.createTHead();
        let row = thead.insertRow();
        for (let key of data) {
          let th = document.createElement("th");
          let text = document.createTextNode(key);
          th.appendChild(text);
          row.appendChild(th);
        }
      }

      function generateTableRows(table, data) {
        let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
        data.map((row, index) => {
          let newCell = newRow.insertCell();
          let newText = document.createTextNode(row);
          newCell.appendChild(newText);
        });
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```